# How do I subscribe to a tag in launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

I'm interested in several tags withing a project's bug report page, but would only like to receive email when a bug is tagged with certain criteria (ie: new-charm) How can I do this in LaunchPad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears this was a 'bug' and has been implemented in the latest build *([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/151129))*, and should be available to you now.

*is this what you are looking for?*
[image]

Comment: It's been around longer than just the latest build. It was deployed somewhere at the end of 2010 I think.

Comment: s/has been/has at least been/

Comment: I can't find how to do this. Where is this screenshot taken, rlemon?